# Eclipse - extending project/package explorer to handle custom file types as trees

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi

If an Eclipse project includes a .jar file, the package explorer treats it like a tree and enables the user to click the "+" sign to the left of the file name to expand the tree and show the files in the .jar archive.

I would like the package explorer to treat other file types the same way. A really simple example would be if the file test.txt containing:

```
First line
Second line
Third line
```

was shown as:

```
-test.txt
--First Line
--Second Line
--Third line
```

I've been trying to find a suitable extension point to do this, but no progress so far. Could someone point my in the right direction? I would like Eclipse to use my plug-in for interpreting the file as a tree as soon as it's added to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to use the common navigation framework:
[CNF](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Common_Navigator_Framework)

Comment: Although already mentioned on that Eclipse Wiki page, I would like to stress that the tutorials on this site are particularly useful and easy to follow: http://scribbledideas.blogspot.com